# Using routing's 'resolve's result later in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a beginner in angularjs. I have the following angular code in routing:

```
  .when('/projectconfig/:projectId', {
  templateUrl: 'views/core/project/project.html',
  controller: 'ProjectConfiguration',
  resolve:{
    projectData: function ($q, $routeParams,ProjectConfiguration, Logger) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      ProjectConfiguration.query({projectId: $routeParams.projectId},
                      function(projectData) {
                                  deferred.resolve(projectData);
                      }, function(errorData) {
                                   Logger.log('Problem in resolution data.');
                                  deferred.reject();
                     });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
})
```

I appreciate some hint how I can later use projectData in my controller that belongs to page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to inject projectData as a parameter in your controller. The UI Router documentation [has an example](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#wiki-resolve) (scroll down to 'controller:' in the code block). Then you'll be able to access it anywhere within your controller.